# when i decrypt base64 string in c# it shows me ????? question mark and some special character sign

Tags: c#, encryption, base64

i have a base64 string and i want to decrypt it thru c# code. but when i apply below code, it shows me question mark and differnt special characters.
i dont know why it is showing this.

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encpStr);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

i created console project in visual studio,   and doing this practice. see my whole code below.

```
string encStr = "oJe6iooq+PbvArD+C7P7B/cHAAL9Dr2/vvIBFRcVCAYfxxEcygzMFB0eFNEWFC3VKibYLCknMiLeLzU7PC8pOPT19g==";

Console.WriteLine("******************\nEnc String:\n" + encStr + "\n\n\n**********************");
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encStr);
string decStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nDecr String: \n" + decStr + "\n\n");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Well, maybe the bytes don't form a UTF8 string. You are confusing encoding and encrypting in you code, that might be a hint.

Comment: Tell us where that encPstr came from and what it is supposed to be. Provide a sample if possible. Otherwise you might as well delete this question.

Comment: ok i edit my question with more detail

Comment: string added, please check now.

Comment: Where did it come from, what do you know about the contents? It doesn't look like Text (ASCII or UTF8) but it doesn't look encrypted either.

Comment: my ex-colleague was working on our website,he was using these strings for some purpose in different modules, he added dlls and then under some dlls again added some dlls, i can not back track the code completely, now more than 2 months he left the job.and today we got an issue in our website, and we are unable to contact him and we want to fix it. i was told by my senior it is base64 just decode quickly. and i find output of question mark as i told u.

Comment: Yes, it is base64 and that gets you  `data = byte[145]`. But those bytes don't mean anything, it's not text. You will have to find some code where it is being created or used, to get a clue.

Comment: is there any help or hint you can give me to sort it out.

Comment: See previous comment. There is nothing to go on here.

Comment: ok thanks Henk Holterman

Comment: Is what you're decoding supposed to be human-readable? Often base64 is used to encode binary data.

Comment: It is not terribly unlikely that encStr was the result of encrypting a string, then encoding the byte[] with base64.  In which case you just went too fast, you forgot to decrypt it.

Comment: I agree with @HenkHolterman's first comment and @HansPassant. Hurrah for partially readable variable names. But if you simply want to avoid the questions marks and get real debugging information that would in part confirm what they are saying, replace `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)` with `new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetString(data)`.

Comment: ok Thank all, i will try it by monday and will let you know.

Comment: You can take a look at the bytes, I did. Not enough enrtropy for real encryption, wrong ranges for ASCII. It could be a simple XOR encryption, or unencrypted binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By default many systems/languages display byte values that can not be represented as a ?, � or similar glyph.
2. Base64 is encoding not encryption.
3. Base64 encoding is generally used when data needs to be handled as a character string but the data values are not representable as characters (or at least not all).

Data is generally a collection of 8-bit bytes such as in an array. Eamples include images, compiled computer code, encrypted data and etc.

Not all, even most, byte values do not have a character representation and do not have a displayable representation. See ASCII, unicode and in particular [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as well as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Answer (score 2):

Base64 is used to encode binary data as text. If you decode Base64 data, you therefore get binary data. Most binary data cannot be represented as a string (or any other form of text) because it simply is not text.

Your Base64 is such an example. The result is not text, neither in UTF-8, nor in ASCII nor in any other encoding.

That's why you get a bunch on funny characters. They are used to represent invalid characters.